# can not center input fields css

Tags: html, css

Sorry I am new to this; trying to build the google webpage for practice . I can't figure out why my to "inputs" don't go to the  center of page.

**HTML:**

```css
#submitsearch {
  text-align:center;
}

#submitsearch [type="submit" ] {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center; 
  background: #D3D3D3;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color:#606060;
}
```

```html
<div id="submitsearch">
   <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
   <input type="submit" value="I'm feeling lucky">
</div>
```

Comment: Please make sure to copy all lines of the issuing part in your code. Add the starting tag of the _div_ so we can understand more your _CSS_

Comment: div : `width: 100% text-align: center;` , input : `margin : 0 auto;`

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle link for more understanding.

Comment: @Radiant Ahmed You can't solve his issue while editing the post, this is not acceptable, you have to post an answer!

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj ok i didnt know that but i did answer before anyone else.....but all in vain because my name wont show and i wont even get good reputation..:(

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div id = "parent">
  <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
         <input type="submit" value="I'm feeling lucky">
      </div>
```

CSS

```
html,body,#parent{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#parent{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/zumodig/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thanks that seems to work!. sorry for the poor formatting.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/Ylama/pen/BJjBeq

```
  <div>
     <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
     <input type="submit" value="I'm feeling lucky">
  </div>
```

CSS

```
 div {width: 100%;text-align: center;}

 input {margin: 0 auto;}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
  <div class="make-inputs-center">
      <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
     <input type="submit" value="I'm feeling lucky">
  </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.make-inputs-center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go about it.

You can make use of `absolute positioning` and `transform the submitsearch` to the center of the page (This allows you to make no changes whatsoever to your parent container):

```css
#submitsearch {
  position:absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
}

#submitsearch [type="submit" ] {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center; 
  background: #D3D3D3;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color:#606060;
}
```

```html
<div id="submitsearch">
   <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
   <input type="submit" value="I'm feeling lucky">
</div>
```

**OR**

Make your `submitsearch` as a **flexbox** and align and justify the contents in the center of the page by increasing its height to 100vh (or increase your body and submitsearch height to 100%):

```css
#submitsearch {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
}

#submitsearch [type="submit" ] {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center; 
  background: #D3D3D3;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color:#606060;
}
```

```html
<div id="submitsearch">
   <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
   <input type="submit" value="I'm feeling lucky">
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Adding the following will do the trick for you

```
margin : 0 auto;
```